# Automated test of deployed applications

Tags: java, automated-tests

Often some testing framework for automated testing - like Selenium - is used  to continiuosly verify the integrity of a deployed application. These tests often cover real user scenarios and may also utilize a range of deployed applications in combination.

We would like to achieve some what the same for a "backend only" application - that is, an application (or more really) without frontend. We are currently building a series of batchjobs where one job produces input to the next.

We have a great unit-test suite that tests the individual jobs however we would really like to test the series of jobs when deployed to some environment.

Do you have any suggestions for such testing framework? The framework must be able to leverage other Java SDKs such as AWS SDK (e.g. to instruct startup of batchjob, inject data to queues etc.). Whether the framework with tests needs to be deployed as an application as well or run directly from CI is secondary.

Comment: Did you check out Arquillian?

Comment: I saw it, read a bit and found it to be wrong for our purpose. It seems - and that just might be my lack of investigation - that Arquillian is for testing services with real data in a real environment instead of mocking services? I you think it might be the right tool for us I will investigate further :)

Comment: Hmm yes, it's probably more useful in integration testing and not mocking services but from your question I was guessing you wanted to do just that :) Anyway, you could use it to deploy your application to some server, prepare your database, start the batch and check the results pretty easily ... if you want to mock services the batch uses that should also possible but a litte more complicated ... and depends a lot on your setup I'd say

Answer (score 0):

If you already have backedn tests that can be run on the production all you need is to schedule running on those tests. Jenkins is fine for that (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Schedule+Build+Plugin)

You could have emails (or other alerts) for failed jobs. Jenkins will also care for test reports- exactly as it does for unit tests.

**Technologies for scheduling test runs**

You could schedule running your tests using any other technology- for example Amazon AWS instances, AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environments (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html) etc.

I find Jenkins most reasonable, because you have out-of-the box support for test reports, notifications, etc.

For any other technologies you would have to write reportting, notifications on your own.

**Technologies for writing tests**

I could write tests in any technology that is capable of making HTTP REST calls. For performance tests Jmeter or Gatling are good choices.

For acceptance test you could use RestEasy, TestRestTemplate from Spring, Apache HTTP client, etc.
As test running framework you could use Junit4,Juni5, TestNG or Spock (if you are fine with Groovy language). Test structure could be similar to those of ordinary tests. Well named independend methods that test one thing well, meaningfull assertions, etc.
For writing assertions my personal preference is AssertJ, but JavaHamcrest would also do.

Those tests can (and should) be written in src/test directory, in separate repository (or in same repository or different module).

For that test module you may write test-releated services in src/main directory, so src/test directory would contain only test scenarios. Test services may everyting you need- manage files, inspect database, etc.

You may consider writting test scenarios in BDD-style and tools like JBehave or Cucumber. Personally I see value in BDD tests only if business is interested in test scenarios. If those tests are to be used only by technical people then I find easier to maintain such tests in non-BDD technologies (Junit, AssertJ).

Comment: We don't - in the sense that we have only unit tests (which aren't deployed of course). What I am looking for is a framework to facilitate backend tests when deployed. Scheduling etc. should be easy enough - it's just a matter of wheter we should write our own testing "framework" or does something exist that could do some nice things for us; e.g. structure of tests, reporting etc.

Comment: So. You are suggesting that we write a test application with tests written in src/main rather than src/test, deploy it and schedule it? It's not merely a matter of calling specific REST APIs but (not limited to): injecting data into application, inspect results in database, manage files etc. The batchjobs have no rest-interfaces and act solely upon data in a database and external systems.